# How to define a function on dbfiddle

Tags: oracle

I have defined a function in dbfiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=caa911153bd911d9f46894d6ad476bf3

It compile on my computer but not  there.

> ORA-24344: success with compilation error

my code if the link dies:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f (p IN integer)
    RETURN INTEGER
IS
BEGIN
    RETURN 1;
END;
```

Comment: Add a `/` on the final line.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ba3b20d1cbb694561dc38d0d59c51f86

Comment: As Justin said, you need to use a PL/SQL statement terminator and put a `/` on a new line at the end of the statement.

Comment: @JustinCave Thanks it was the problem. But know I can't create a type for a different reason that I can't find (see updated function)

Comment: @MT0  Thanks it was the problem. But know I can't create a type for a different reason that I can't find. (see updated question)

Comment: A `record` is a PL/SQL type so it would need to be declared inside a PL/SQL block.  If you want to create a roughly similar type in SQL, you'd want to create an object type `create type type_name as object ...`.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=61196249d25348cea6e411fff536b3cf is valid but I don't know if it's what you actually want.

Comment: Please do not edit the question to fundamentally change it. If you have a follow up question then ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to MT0 and JustinCave:

2 Problems:
- I forget / at the end of the definition
- I forget the keyword CREATE

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=61196249d25348cea6e411fff536b3cf

Comment: Well, the / doesn't really belong to the PL/SQL block. It is required by Oracles sql\*plus console only. It seems hence that dbfiddle.uk uses sql\*plus internally and doesn't add the / itself. I wouldn't say you *forgot* to add the /. You merely didn't now that dbfiddle.uk requires it.